# I need to write a .DDS file cross-platform, can someone point me to example?

Tags: windows, image, macos, directdraw, dds-format

I need to create a .DDS file with code that runs on both OSX and Windows. Although the format doesn't look difficult, I'd still like an example of writing the file. Note I don't need to read it, just write it.

C or C++ and RGBA bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resorted to written a RAW file, and using GraphicConvertor (mac) to read it and write the DDS file. I think Photoshop can do it too. RAW files are simply RGB or RGBA or similar formats written straight to a binary file. Then in the reading application you tell it the dimensions so it can read it in. Then you export to whatever. Not a perfect solution but it worked for what I needed.